# remove IDs that occur x times R

Tags: r, rows

I have a df and I would like to remove people who have less than X amount of rows in df. E.g., in this toy example, I would like to retain people who have >= 5 rows.

```
df
   names  fruit
4   john   kiwi
7   john  apple
9   john banana
13  john orange
14  john  apple
2   mary orange
5   mary  apple
8   mary orange
10  mary  apple
12  mary  apple
1    tom  apple
3    tom banana
6    tom  apple
11   tom   kiwi
```

example output

```
df
   names  fruit
4   john   kiwi
7   john  apple
9   john banana
13  john orange
14  john  apple
2   mary orange
5   mary  apple
8   mary orange
10  mary  apple
12  mary  apple
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `table` like this:

```
df[df$names %in% names(table(df$names))[table(df$names) >= 5],]
```

Comment: excellent stuff. Thank you. Just to highlight that the "names" that occurs directly after %in% is part of the syntax for the function and does not refer to the column called "names" in my df.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a `data.table` solution using the in-built `.N` value, which is as described in the `?data.table` help file: *`‘.N’ is an integer, length 1, containing the number of rows in the group.`*

```
#create a similar reproducible exmaple
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(names=rep(letters[1:3],c(5,5,3)),var=1:13)
```

Remove the rows:

```
dat[, cnt:=.N, by=names][cnt >= 5]
```

Though I feel like there must be a way to do this without assigning a new variable.
...And now there is thanks to @mnel in the comments:

```
dat[,if(.N>=5).SD,by=names]
```

This essentially returns a sub-data.table `.SD` for each value of the `by` group if the number of rows in the group `.N` is greater than or equal to 5. It is pretty much equivalent to the more traditional R subsetting syntax of:

```
dat[,.SD[.N >= 5],by=names]
```

Comment: `dat[,if(.N>=5).SD,by=names]`

Comment: @Mnel makes a great point.  The advantage to using the `if` statement in `j` is that it avoids the overhead of calling `.SD` when the clause evaluates to `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution could be to use the `subset()` command as below:

```
subset(df, ave(names, names, FUN = length) >= 5)
```

Or alternatively,

```
df[ave(df$names, df$names, FUN = length) >= 5, ]
```