# Select groups based on number of unique / distinct values

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a data frame like below

```
sample <- data.frame(ID = 1:9,
                     Group = c('AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','CC','CC','BB','CC'),
                     Value = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,3))

ID       Group    Value
1        AA       1
2        AA       1
3        AA       1
4        BB       2
5        BB       2
6        CC       2
7        CC       3
8        BB       2
9        CC       3
```

I want to select groups according to the number of distinct (unique) values within each group. For example, select groups where all values within the group are the same (one distinct value per group). If you look at the group CC, it has more than one distinct value (2 and 3) and should thus be removed. The other groups, with only one distinct value, should be kept. Desired output:

```
ID       Group    Value
1        AA       1
2        AA       1
3        AA       1
4        BB       2
5        BB       2
8        BB       2
```

Would you tell me simple and fast code in R that solves the problem?

Comment: What have you done to try to solve the problem?

Comment: I used the answer that I checked.

Comment: I translated this post to share with Korean developers on [ctrlaltdel](http://ctrlaltdel.co.kr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a selector for `sample` using `ave` many different ways.

```
sample[ ave( sample$Value, sample$Group, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) ) == 1,]
```

or

```
sample[ ave( sample$Value, sample$Group, FUN = function(x) sum(x - x[1]) ) == 0,]
```

or

```
sample[ ave( sample$Value, sample$Group, FUN = function(x) diff(range(x)) ) == 0,]
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

sample <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:9,  
  Group= c('AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC', 'BB', 'CC'),  
  Value = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3)
)

sample %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Value) == 1)
```

We group the data by `Group`, and then only select groups where the number of distinct values of `Value` is 1.

Answer (score 7):

`data.table` version:

```
library(data.table)
sample <- as.data.table(sample)
sample[ , if(uniqueN(Value) == 1) .SD, by = Group]

#   Group ID Value
#1:    AA  1     1
#2:    AA  2     1
#3:    AA  3     1
#4:    BB  4     2
#5:    BB  5     2
#6:    BB  8     2
```

An alternative using `ave` if the data is numeric, is to check if the variance is 0:

```
sample[with(sample, ave(Value, Group, FUN=var ))==0,]
```

---

An alternative solution that could be faster on large data is:

```
setkey(sample, Group, Value)
ans <- sample[unique(sample)[, .N, by=Group][N==1, Group]]
```

The point is that calculating `unique` values for each group could be time consuming when there are more groups. Instead, we can set the key on the `data.table`, then take `unique` values by key (which is extremely fast) and then count the total values for each group. We then require only those where it is 1. We can then perform a `join` (which is once again very fast). Here's a benchmark on large data:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
sample <- data.table(ID=1:1e7, 
        Group = sample(rep(paste0("id", 1:1e5), each=100)), 
        Value = sample(2, 1e7, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9, 0.1)))

system.time (
    ans1 <- sample[,if(length(unique(Value))==1) .SD ,by=Group]
)
# minimum of three runs
#   user  system elapsed 
# 14.328   0.066  14.382 

system.time ({
    setkey(sample, Group, Value)
    ans2 <- sample[unique(sample)[, .N, by=Group][N==1, Group]]
})
# minimum of three runs
#   user  system elapsed 
#  5.661   0.219   5.877 

setkey(ans1, Group, ID)
setkey(ans2, Group, ID)
identical(ans1, ans2) # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - I remember discussing with mnel [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18304851/496803) that using `if` is slightly quicker or more efficient. I can't recall why though.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, and that makes perfect sense! Using `if` saves the call to `.SD`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach

```
> ind <- aggregate(Value~Group, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))==1, data=sample)[,2]
> sample[sample[,"Group"] %in% levels(sample[,"Group"])[ind], ]
  ID Group Value
1  1    AA     1
2  2    AA     1
3  3    AA     1
4  4    BB     2
5  5    BB     2
8  8    BB     2
```