# How to subset only the rows that have multiple, different values in another column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataset similar to that below:

```
zz <-  "Session    Rater     
1          A         X          
2          A         X     
3          A         X   
4          B         Y   
5          B         Y     
6          B         Z   
7          B         Z         
8          C         X   
9          C         Y    
10         C         Z"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

I'd like to only subset the session rows for which the session has multiple raters, even though that data is stored in another column. Therefore, I'd like end up with a dataset that looks like this:

```
zz2 <-  "Session    Rater     
1          B         Y
2          B         Y
3          B         Z
4          B         Z
5          C         X
6          C         Y
7          C         Z"

Data2 <- read.table(text=zz2, header = TRUE)
```

Where Session A rows were removed from the dataset because Session A only had one rater, "X," but Sessions B and C (and all of their rows) were retained because they had more than one rater (Y & Z for Session B, and X, Y, & Z for Session C).

I've played around with `dplyr`, but with no success. Many thanks.

Comment: Essentially the opposite of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421031/eliminate-groups-which-have-different-values-in-r/21421184 and arguably a duplicate given that all you have to change is `==` to `>`, but some things have moved on from those answers too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `filter` with `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
    group_by(Session) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(Rater)>1)
#  Session  Rater
#   <fctr> <fctr>
#1       B      Y
#2       B      Y
#3       B      Z
#4       B      Z
#5       C      X
#6       C      Y
#7       C      Z
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, if(uniqueN(Rater)>1)  .SD, by = Session]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
i1 <- rowSums(!!table(Data))
subset(Data, Session %in% names(i1)[i1 >1])
```

Answer (score 1):

... or using ave() and subscripting (assuming Rater is a factor, which is the default when reading character data)

```
Data[with(Data,ave(unclass(Rater),Session,
FUN = function(x)length(unique(x)))) > 1,]
```