# Selecting data based on different values in the same column and unique value in another column in R

Tags: r, select, subset

Sorry if the title is confusing, wasn't sure how to describe this problem. Ok so I have a dataframe with one column that is sampling site, of which I have many, and one column that is sampling method, of which there are only two. Here's a simplified version:

```
site <- c("X", "Y", "X","Z") 
method <- c("A", "B", "B", "A")
data <- data.frame(site, method)
data
  site method
1    X      A
2    Y      B
3    X      B
4    Z      A
```

Now some sites got sampled using both sampling method A and method B, and some got sampled by only method A or method B.

I am trying to select only those sites that got sampled using both methods. For example, the output for this data would look like this:

```
     site method
  1    X      A
  2    X      B
```

I don't have a sample code because I honestly do not know how to do this. Please help!

Comment: Similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421031/eliminate-groups-which-have-different-values-in-r/21421184 - and the linked questions there are also very similar.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'site', `if` the length of the unique 'method' is greater than 1, then get the Subset of Data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, if(uniqueN(method)>1) .SD , by = site]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we can do it.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(site) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(method)>1)
```

---

A possible `base R` option would be

```
data[ with(data, ave(method, site, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))>1)),]
```