# Return df with a columns values that occur more than once

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame df, and I am trying to subset all rows that have a value in column `B` occur more than once in the dataset.

I tried using table to do it, but am having trouble subsetting from the table:

```
t<-table(df$B)
```

Then I try subsetting it using:

```
subset(df, table(df$B)>1)
```

And I get the error

> "Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset)] : 
>     object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

How can I subset my data frame using table counts?

Comment: I was looking at the plyr function count as well, but that creates an entirely new data frame.

Comment: Well, all of these methods will create a new data.frame (or data.table). R generally doesn't modify objects in place.

Answer (score 34):

Here is a `dplyr` solution  (using mrFlick's  data.frame)

```
library(dplyr)
newd <-  dd %>% group_by(b) %>% filter(n()>1) #
newd
#    a b 
# 1  1 1 
# 2  2 1 
# 3  5 4 
# 4  6 4 
# 5  7 4 
# 6  9 6 
# 7 10 6
```

Or, using data.table

```
setDT(dd)[,if(.N >1) .SD,by=b]
```

Or using base R

```
dd[dd$b %in% unique(dd$b[duplicated(dd$b)]),]
```

Comment: dd%>%group_by(b) %>%filter(n()>1) #should also work. Or dd%>%group_by(b) %>%filter(length(row_number())>1)

Answer (score 6):

May I suggest an alternative, faster way to do this with `data.table`?

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
setDT(df)[, .N, by=B][N > 1L]$B
```

(or) you can couple `.I` (another special variable - see `?data.table`) which gives the corresponding row number in `df`, along with `.N` as follows:

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[.N > 1L], by=B]$V1]
```

(or) have a look at @mnel's another for another variation (using yet another special variable `.SD`).

Comment: can you explain the .N?

Comment: yeah sure thing.  The .N returns the count (or length) for each group.  This syntax is grouping by B and showing the count as the aggregated statistic.  Then it is filtering by the values of B that have a count greater than 1.

Comment: If you are familiar with sql, this is very analogous.  df[where,select,groupby][having]

Comment: @ChrisRobles - more explanation here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18304851/496803

Answer (score 5):

Using `table()` isn't the best because then you have to rejoin it to the original rows of the data.frame. The `ave` function makes it easier to calculate row-level values for different groups. For example

```
dd<-data.frame(
    a=1:10,
    b=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6, 6)
)


dd[with(dd, ave(b,b,FUN=length))>1, ]
#subset(dd, ave(b,b,FUN=length)>1)    #same thing

    a b
1   1 1
2   2 1
5   5 4
6   6 4
7   7 4
9   9 6
10 10 6
```

Here, for each level of `b`, it counts the length of `b`, which is really just the number of `b`'s and returns that back to the appropriate row for each value. Then we use that to subset.

Comment: `with(dd, dd[b %in% names(table(b))[table(b) > 1],])` would allow you to use `table`, albeit not as cleanly.

Comment: Right. I hate having to call it twice like that. This is one of places I might use a [withX()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/35ff2265619762d49159) function: `dd[dd$b %in% withX(table(dd$b), names(X[X>1])), ]`. Or you could even use `names(Filter(function(x) x>1, table(dd$b)))` to get the names out. But that still converts them to character. But that's why I say it's "not the best" rather than not possible.