# Removing rows based upon frequency of factor/categorical value in a column

Tags: r, subset, regression, cross-validation, training-data

I have a dataset that I will be performing cross validation training upon.  However, due to this splitting of the data, I sometimes encounter errors because the factor level found in the test set was not found in the training set ---- because this factor might occur a very limited number of times.

I would like a way to easily filter out these rows prior to doing any cross validation to avoid errors...

for example, how would I check to make sure that the factors that contain 9 or less observations are removed?

```
mtcars$carb = factor(mtcars$carb)
table(mtcars$carb)
```

Comment: Essentially the same as [remove-ids-that-occur-x-times-r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302610/remove-ids-that-occur-x-times-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using library `dplyr`, you can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% filter(n() > 9)
```

Alternatively, you can re-factor the variable in training set and remove any levels not in training data from the test set.

Comment: Base version - `with(mtcars, mtcars[carb %in% levels(carb)[table(carb) > 9],])`